# Enable JMX for Amazon MQ

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mq

Is there a way to connect to Amazon MQ via JMX?

I tried to look at [configure JMX for ActiveMQ for remoting access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725202/configure-jmx-for-activemq-for-remoting-access) but I end up with this once I save the config

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not supported, unless things have changed since this [thread from 2018](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=274688):

> *Amazon MQ does not support JMX access at this time.*

Answer (score 0):

Jmx is not supported in Amazon AMQ. We can use statisticsBrokerPlugin https://activemq.apache.org/statisticsplugin
By enabling this plugin we can fetch broker and its destinations(queue/topic) metrics.